# how to get the dual of that optimization problem

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

max $1^\top x$ such that $x^\top M x = 0$ and $x_i^2 = x_i$ for all i

For the above problem how can I derive the dual form. My main problem is to choose matrix notation or the element-wise notation as I am deriving the dual. This conflict is cause by the constraint $x_i^2 = x_i$.

Would you describe the solution or at lest some tips to dwell into the derivation?

Comment: Is $1^\top$ supposed to represent the row vector of $1$s (of appropriate length)?

Comment: yes it is 1's vector in required size